# Disable root login for embedded linux production environment?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, production-environment

I am working on a project that runs embedded linux.  I want two user groups, one with limited admin access and another with basic read only access.  Neither will have full root access.

Is root login normally disabled for products like this?  If yes, let's say the user forgets their account passwords.  They want to reset the password, but how is this accomplished without any root access?

Comment: Most embedded products I have worked on uses only the root account.  If there needs to be restrictions, the application enforces it.  However, none of my products permits direct Linux access except for manufacturing.

Comment: For the most part root is the only login account on embedded systems. There are no remote shell listening on any network port. Direct login to the device is prohibited to end users. Developers can access the login via the serial console only. Some manufacturers go as far as making a proprietary serial console connector in order to prevent unauthorized used (security by obscurity). End users interact with the device via a user application running on top of the kernel. If they forget their access creds they can reset the system without affecting the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most boxes are designed with a reset button that can act as a 'reboot' button or if held down during boot up, a 'reset to factory defaults'.

If the user forgets their password, they need to reset the entire box and lose their existing config. You do not under any circumstances want to give someone the ability to reset a password (without root access) without physical access to the box.

At the absolute least ( physical access && config-wipe ) should always be the prerequisite for this operation.

Root accounts are usually disabled unless your reset to factory defaults is bulletproof (i.e. you have a spare copy of firmware in a hidden area that you can always restore to)